# Debugging with Mono Tools 2 beta on Visual Studio 2008 - getting "Failed to start XSP!" error

Tags: mono, xsp

I'm trying to run a .NET web application through Mono. I'm using Mono Tools 2.0 beta on VS 2008 and trying to debug locally (directly on Windows).

When I just "Run in Mono", the application launches fine -- even though I get a fatal exception which I'll deal with once I get debug mode working.

But when I "Debug in Mono", I see the Mono console window pop up, stay there without displaying any messages for a while and then I get an error dialog saying "Failed to start XSP!".

I'm looking advice in troubleshooting this problem since I'm still trying to ramp up on Mono concepts/architecture.

Comment: This happened when using Mono 2.6.4 with Mono Tools 2 beta BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simultaneously asked this question on a Mono IRC channel and got a resolution. It turns out Mono 2.6.4 was incompatible with Mono Tools 2 beta. On the same release notes page from which I downloaded Mono Tools 2 beta, there was a link to Mono 2.6.5. Upgrading to 2.6.5 fixed the problem.